# Small application gets "didReceiveMemoryWarning" right after start

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, multitasking, didreceivememorywarning

Often, when a lot of applications were opened before my application I get "didReceiveMemoryWarning" and then, after a while iOS usually closes my application.
This is actually become a noticeable problem.

I have read so much so much consider to "didReceiveMemoryWarning" for the last few days. Including posts here. Unfortunately no solution found.

I know that I have to release any memory on this warning and bla-bla-bla…
The problem is that right after application start there is nothing to release. I have one UIViewControlled in memory with AdMob 4.0.2 banner and one own container that serves application data - which is a few records in NSMuttableArray. 
Right after start my application takes 1.3 Mb – according to Instruments and at this initial state my application was not working and I definately know no memory leaks.

What is wrong?
I see that some of the heavy games can be started with no problems, but in the same time my application in this case gets "didReceiveMemoryWarning" and is closed.
Is there a way work in normal way in this situation.
Is there some tricks?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What does the Instrument's Leak tool say regarding memory leaks ?

Comment: Have you checked this in device. My advice is to just restart your device. May be it contains a lot of apps in background.

Comment: Restart device of course help - BUT this is not the solution for application that is going to the market. Some heavy games could be started and work well on my device without device restart and they have no problems with memory.

Comment: 2 DarkDust: Memory leaks occurs in AdMob SDK 4.0.2 - BUT, actually, it is very small amount of memory. Something like 100-200kb for session. These leaks appears on the start and then stops. I've checked my application by Instruments. It starts generate memory warning when 3.5-4Mb is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you allocating the NSMUtableArray? I think it's being allocated often! (Just a probability...) Do you releasing the NSMutableArray?

Comment: NSMutableArray created once on start and releases on exit.